# apache invalid command 'ScriptAlias'

Tags: apache, debian

I am trying to get apache2 running but no matter what I do, localhost comes up as 404 not found.

*There has been so many errors that Debian doesn't even think Apache2 is installed, but it is functional, and running. But I cannot remove it with --purge or otherwise.*

When I start apache I get

```
root@debian:/tmp# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
Invalid command 'ScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
failed!
```

Here is site file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried various configurations. My goal is to utilize multiple IPs for different virtual hosts on port 80, but I haven't even gotten it to work after my last disaster and re installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ScriptAlias is provided by mod_alias.  On debian based distributions, use a2enmod to make sure mod_alias is loaded:
`sudo a2enmod alias`